# views_slideshow's alternate pagination

Tags: jquery, drupal-6, pagination

I've created a slider on the front page of a website using views_slideshow in Drupal 6. I have all the functionality except for a custom pager. I have the numeric pager (i.e. 1 2 3 4 5 6 7), but *my spec requires these to be simple text bullets*. I could easily do this with images in css, but can I achieve a uniform character for all links in the views_slideshow pagination?

I've been looking at the advanced options in the slideshow settings when building my view. I have tried adding something like:

`pagerAnchorBuilder:  var return_var = '<li><a href="#">o</a></li>'`

I read elsewhere in Drupal forums that this field will not accept a function as a return, so we must do it like above. Others are having this issue, but I have not been able to find a response. Any thoughts?

Comment: To be clear, I am seeking a solution that *does not use images*. I am looking for the acceptable syntax for using pagerAnchorBuilder in the advanced options field of the views_slideshow module in Drupal 6.

Comment: **Solution:** I was using the single frame module that utilizes views_slideshow. If you use ThumbnailHover instead, it allows you to specify a field as a custom pager. For consistency, (since I wanted a uniform character), I overwrote the output of that field in the fields area of the views. Vola! Custom pager without having to use advance jQuery options. Good video here that shows the first steps: [UCI Video Walkthrough](http://replay.uci.edu/clients/drupal/Views_Slideshow_and_Dynamic_Display_Block_-_Web_(1024x768)_-_20100807_02.53.58PM.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with CSS only. Assuming this HTML source:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
</ul>    


ul{overflow:hidden}
li a{float:left;width:10px;height:10px;background:red;margin-right:5px;display:block;text-indent:-999em}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas_peklak/svE9T/)

Just use a background image instead of the color.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm looking for the jquery override related to the Drupal views_slideshow module in Drupal 6. My requirements do not allow for an image background in place of a bullet. I think floating the text out of view is an inelegant solution, although I certainly appreciate your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about this patch?
[make pagerAnchorBuilder themeable](http://drupal.org/node/593710)

Comment: Thank you. I did check that patch, and it's already been folded into the module. I was still having problems with the syntax, however. This is more along the lines of the answer I was looking for, though. thanks for the response!